# how to make sure a trace listener flushes the underyling buffer before program termination

Tags: c#, io, trace

I'm using my own trace listener to output message to files. For good performance, I've set autoflush to false in my App.Config. So I need to make sure myself the underlying buffer will always be flushed to disk even encounter unexpected/abnormal program termination, e.g. terminate the program while debugging. I thought this might be a general problem, is there any elegant solution?

Comment: FileOptions.WriteThrough.  No, it isn't elegant.  Check [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2012/08/13/windows-high-speed-logging-etw-in-c-net-using-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no easy way to do this.

You can expose a method that manually flushes the buffers. Specifically, when .NET application crashes with unhandled exception you can register an AppDomain handler. This handler can call the buffer flush method.

However some exceptions may or may not lead to executing unhandled exception handler in the domain. I believe they are `StackoverflowException`, `OutOfMemoryException` and `ThreadAbortedException`, perhaps a few other specific to CLR itself.

But in general case, you should be good to flush the buffer here [AppDomain::UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx).

I don't think this will flush the buffers when you deliberately kill an application.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object with a destructor. Flush in the destructor. [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx) destructors are called when the program exits. I'm still trying to find out whether this will work if your program crashes.

Comment: Destructor aka *finalizer* is not a good place for this.  In a finalizer, other disposable objects (like your `DbConnection`) might or might not be disposed already.  Finalizers are for cleaning up **unmanaged** resources (like a temp file).  Anything else is asking for trouble.  See [Microsoft's guidance for disposable types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern).